# Change startup project automatically

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Just had an unfortunate accident in a multi-project solution where after adding a new project to the solution, writing some code and hitting `F5` the project that ran wasn't the one in focus. Is there any way to make Visual studio automatically mark a new project as the startup one?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but deciding which project should be the startup one tends to be a one-off decision most of the time.

Comment: there is the automartic way: after adding a project automatically rightklick on the project and set it as startup project

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever in production sure, but during development I tend to write several project and test them separately.

Comment: @giammin that is not really automatic

Comment: @Yoav yes but it is only one click...

Comment: @giammin I know, but sometimes i forget that click as mentioned in my question and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 27):

The options for startup projects can be found by right-clicking on the solution and selecting "Set Startup Projects".  The options are pretty straightforward:

- Current selection
- Single startup project
- Multiple startup projects

Comment: That isn't automatic though.

Comment: Boom! That's the answer I've been looking for. Thank you.

Comment: You can also right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and select "Set as StartUp Project". Still not automatic, but a little simpler than right-clicking the solution and navigating the menus.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something in Visual Studio that allows you to run the project without worrying about setting a Startup Project and let Visual Studio decide depending on the current selection. To achieve this, right-click on the solution explorer, choose properties. Next select Startup Project, from there select Current Selection from the Radio Button List. 
By doing this,whatever project you highlight in the Solution Explorer (or file you select in the text editor) will now become the current startup project.

Answer (score 1):

The F5 button is tied to whatever project is marked as "startup" and imho having VS "switch" startup project would be an awful feature and one of the first I'd disable after installing.

However, you can set a shortcut for starting new project instance via class view context menu, open Tools->Options->Keyboard and filter the list for "ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Debug.Startnewinstance", set it's shortcut below for something handy like Alt + F5 (yes, you can replace just the F5 if you want). You can now run "current" project (project that holds currently focused source file or parent project of a file selected in the class view etc.) with this shortcut.

Comment: There's already a feature for it, see @Jimmy's answer. Just because one person finds it "awful" doesn't mean others shouldn't have the flexibility to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set a shortcut for swapping the start up project, if that helps

`Project.SetasStartupProject` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (for example)

[image]

https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2007/07/30/visual-studio-tricks-series-1-set-as-startup-project/